# I can't see background color in android phone ( 7.0 ) but in a tablet I can

Tags: android, html, css, flexbox

Happy New Year

I made a website that has a background color.

You can see the backgroung color in 3 mayor browsers in a desktop

On an IPad, in Safari and Chrome I can see the background and it's border

BUT

In my Galaxy 6, with Android 7.0 I can't see the backgrond nor the borders of the designed webpage

Thanks in advance for your help

here is the code where I have the color and borders

```
.main-container {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
align-items: baseline;
background-color: hsl(14, 100%, 53%);
align-items: baseline;
max-width: 1000px;
margin: 0 auto;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 5px;
border-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There could two reasons why you can't see the background color on your Galaxy 6.

1. This could be down to the browser cache which may need clearing.
2. Hue, Saturation, and Lightness is only supported by certain browser versions.

HSL is supported on the following browsers: IE9+, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and in Opera 10+

Comment: Hi there, I tried both suggestions, changing the hsl colors for plain orange and wiping the cache in y cell phone. the situation has not changed. Thank you James